# Company Border in LaTeX

Tags: text, header, format, latex, border

I would like to add a border for both the text and header in LaTeX. I have it in word and I tried to implement it in LaTeX using Tables, but was unsuccessful.

[Page in word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkXH9.png)

Does anyone have a clue how to make this format in LaTeX for every page?

I have done the border of the format. However, I need to add the text with adjustable text boxes for every box.

This is the latex code:

```
\usepackage{kantlipsum} %bla, bla
\usepackage{xsavebox} %save content for repeated use
\usepackage{atbegshi} %insert material on every page



\xsavebox{PageBGPicture}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (4cm,1cm) -- (4cm,27.3cm);
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (4cm,27.3cm) -- (22.3cm,27.3cm);
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (22.3cm,27.3cm) -- (22.3cm,1cm);
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (4cm,1cm) -- (22.3cm,1cm);
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (4cm,23.7cm) -- (22.3cm,23.7cm);
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (8.8cm,27.3cm) -- (8.8cm,23.7cm);
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (17.5cm,27.3cm) -- (17.5cm,23.7cm);
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (8.8cm,26.4cm) -- (22.3cm,26.4cm);
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (17.5cm,25.5cm) -- (22.3cm,25.5cm);
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (17.5cm,24.6cm) -- (22.3cm,24.6cm);
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (19.9cm,23.7cm) -- (19.9cm,24.6cm);
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (21.3cm,26.1cm) -- (21.3cm,26.4cm);
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (4cm,25.2cm) -- (8.8cm,25.2cm);
    \draw[line width=0.001cm] (19.9cm,27.3cm) -- (19.9cm,26.4cm);

    \tikzset{shift={(0,-15)}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

%position background picture absolutely (w.r.t. upper left page corner) on every page
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
8 \put(0.07\paperwidth,-\paperheight+1.5cm){\xusebox{PageBGPicture}}}
}
```